# Using Fibers to create a REPL

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, fibers

I'm trying to use Ruby's Fibers to create a REPL, with one Fiber acting as the frontend - taking input and displaying output - and one Fiber as backend - processing input from the frontend and returning output for display.

(I'm doing this partly because I vaguely need a REPL, partly because I wanted to understand Fibers, and partly because I figured this would allow testing - simply replace the frontend in the test framework to test the backend, and vice-versa).

Trouble is, I can't find any good documentation on how to actually use the full Fibers library, and my initial guess doesn't work. So, I have four questions:

1. Is this a halfway-sensible idea? Am I going to run into huge trouble trying to make a REPL from Fibers?
2. I don't think I can do this without the Fibers library, since I need to pass values both ways. Is that right?
3. Can anyone point me at decent, start-at-the-beginning tutorials or documentation on Ruby Fibers (as in the library, not the unidirectional generators stuff)?
4. Why doesn't the following work? It correctly displays `Enter a string:`, and repeatedly accepts input; but every time I supply a line of input, it just displays the *first* line of input reversed (sample output is included, in case that wasn't clear).

Code:

```
require 'fiber'


# Simple REPL. Echo back the user's input, reversed, until they
# enter "pots" (resulting in "stop")
frontend = Fiber.new do |backend, output|
  while output != 'stop' do
    puts output
    print ": "
    input = gets
    output = backend.transfer(frontend, input)
  end
end

backend = Fiber.new do |frontend, input|
  loop do
    frontend.transfer(input.reverse)
  end
end

frontend.transfer(backend, "Enter a string:")
```

Output:

```
Enter a string:
: Hello

olleH
: World

olleH
:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers, in order:

1. Fibers are wrong for this. Fibers are a very high level feature meant for cooperative concurrency. Using them for a simple use case covered by functions and blocks doesn't make sense.
2. No. Look at your REPL, written using only methods:

   ```
   def repl(output, &backend)
     input = nil
     while output != "stop"
       puts output
       print ': '
       input = gets.chomp
       output = backend.call(input)
     end
   end
   repl("Enter a string: ") {|input| input.reverse}
   ```

   Which outputs:

   ```
   Enter a string:                                                                                                                      
   : Hi                                                                                                                                 
   iH                                                                                                                                   
   : Hello                                                                                                                              
   olleH
   : Bork
   kroB
   ```

   Works perfectly.
3. Ruby's own documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fiber.html
4. When you call `transfer` or `resume` multiple times, the arguments are only passed to the block of the fiber the first time. So each time you call `transfer` the backed fiber is still reversing the first string it was passed, because it never got another. That's why fibers are wrong for implementing this.

Comment: Ah, Answer 3 helps a lot; changing my backend to contain `_, input = frontend.transfer(input.reverse)` makes it work properly. I'm interested what makes Fibers not suited here; AIUI, they're used when you have two "processes" which each need to block waiting for data from the other. How is that not this situation? Is it just a matter of insufficient complexity?

Comment: @Chowlett: it is this situation, but missing the crucial part. Your frontend and backend arn't *processes*. They have no changing state, no state to change over multiple requests. If your backend was a, say, irb backend, that could be a fiber because it is a process with state. But the frontend? There' son state there at all.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the clarification. FWIW, my backend would need to have state; but my frontend isn't likely to, so I shall go for a simpler solution.